Docker on Windows: OCI runtime create failed: unable to start container process: "bash": no such file or directory
I'm trying to run a Docker container on my Windows machine to execute some reformatting commands using poetry, isort, and black. Here is the relevant part of my Makefile:
.PHONY: reformat
reformat:
    docker run --rm \
        --name container-name \
        -v $(shell pwd)/src:/opt/datahub-consumer/src \
        -v $(shell pwd)/tests:/opt/datahub-consumer/tests \
        $(CONTAINER_NAME) /bin/bash -c "poetry run isort . && poetry run black . --exclude venv"

However, when I run the make reformat command, I get the following error:
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown.

It looks like Docker is trying to use a Windows path for bash, but this should be executed inside the Linux container. How can I modify my setup to ensure that the command is run correctly inside the container?
What I Have Tried:

Verified that bash is accessible from Git Bash by running which bash, which outputs:
/usr/bin/bash
Tested using sh instead of bash in the Docker command, but it still results in errors.
Checked Docker Desktop settings to ensure WSL integration is enabled.

